# How to handle device rotation properly with ViewPager and Page Margin

Tags: android, rotation, android-viewpager, margin, offset

I'm using viewpager for showing the content of a folder. Between the pages i have a page margin of 96 pixels. To handle configuration changes, I added following lines to the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
        android:name="SimpleFilePreviewerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
 </activity>
```

Starting at the very left page, everything is handled as desired when I rotate my device.
Yet, on the next pages, after rotation the view is no longer centered on the screen, instead it has an offset which gets even worse when the ViewPager is swiped further right.

When touching the screen after screen rotation, the displayed view will corrently center itself again.
This offset only occurs when Page Margin is set grater then 0.

Is this a known bug? Is there any way to encounter this offset problem?

Thanks in advance,

Flo

Comment: We have the exact same problem. It started happening after we updated the version of the support library

Comment: I made a test project and reported the issue with Google: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39287

Comment: Still running into this, 8 years later. Anyone found a good fix?